# 404 (Not Found) errors when converting a web app into Lorca desktop app

Tags: javascript, http, go, http-status-code-404

## Background

There is a web app of https://threejs.org/editor/ with its source code as part of three.js repository:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/editor

I'm trying to use the above with [Lorca](https://github.com/zserge/lorca) to create a desktop app version of the web app.

## First approach

As sugggested [here](https://github.com/zserge/lorca/issues/59#issuecomment-492341116), I use the Lorca [counter example](https://github.com/zserge/lorca/tree/master/examples/counter) as a base. I copy the counter example in this location:

```
/home/m3/go/src/lorca-3d-editor
```

Then I clone the three.js at this location:

```
/home/m3/repos/three.js
```

The three.js editor would be at:

```
/home/m3/repos/three.js/editor
```

Now, I change the Lorca counter example source code like this, note that `http.Dir()`
is setting an absolute path:

```golang
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer ln.Close()
    go http.Serve(ln, http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/m3/repos/three.js/editor")))
    ui.Load(fmt.Sprintf("http://%s", ln.Addr()))
```

The commit diff would be:

[image: Commit]

But I get these `404 (Not Found)` errors:

[image: Errors]

## Second approach

I keep a copy of Lorca counter example here:

```
/home/m3/go/src/lorca-3d-editor
```

Then, I copy the whole three.js source code over here:

```
/home/m3/go/src/lorca-3d-editor/three.js
```

So, the web app source code would be at:

```
/home/m3/go/src/lorca-3d-editor/three.js/editor
```

Now, I change the Lorca counter example source code like this, note that `http.Dir("three.js/editor")` is setting a relative path:

```golang
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer ln.Close()
    go http.Serve(ln, http.FileServer(http.Dir("three.js/editor")))
    ui.Load(fmt.Sprintf("http://%s", ln.Addr()))
```

Now I'm getting some `404 (Not Found)` again:

[image: Errors screenshot]

## Possible problem

Possibly, the problem is that the web app inside `three.js/editor` is referencing some files throughout the `three.js` repository. But when serving a Go HTTP server of static files inside `three.js/editor`, the HTTP server cannot find all the external files which are scattered throughout `three.js` repository referenced by contents of `three.js/editor` or contents of `three.js` repository itself. What would be the best practice to resolve such problem?

Comment: @blackgreen Right, I used Go `embed` feature and the problem is solved =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a copy of Lorca counter example here:

```
/home/m3/go/src/lorca-3d-editor
```

Also, keeping the whole three.js source code at:

```
/home/m3/go/src/lorca-3d-editor/three.js
```

So, the web app source code would be at:

```
/home/m3/go/src/lorca-3d-editor/three.js/editor
```

Now, the problem is resolved by such a commit:

[image: Commit]

Now ThreeJS editor runs fine by Lorca:

[image: ThreeJS editor screenshot]